# Grizzly / Jersey resources inside an executable generated with launch4j

Tags: java, grizzly, launch4j, jersey-1.0

I am having issues running a Grizzly Web Server with Jersey Resources when the web server is run from an executable generated by launch4j. The resources are inside the executable generated by launch4j, but the program cannot access them. If I execute it from the jar directly it runs without problems. But I need to provide an .exe to run the webserver.

### Webserver code:

```
String uri = buildURI();
HashMap<String,String> initParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
initParams.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, "my.packages.resources");
initParams.put(WebAppResourceConfig.FEATURE_XMLROOTELEMENT_PROCESSING, "true");
initParams.put(FeaturesAndProperties.FEATURE_FORMATTED, "true");
HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(uri, initParams);
httpServer.start();
```

I have a class in my.packages.resources called InfoRestResource with the following code:

```
@Path("/info")
public class InfoRestResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/time")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getTime() {
        return String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
    }
}
```

### launchj4 Maven configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bluestemsoftware.open.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>launch4j</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>launch4j</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
                <headerType>console</headerType>
                <jar>${basedir}/target/my-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar>
                <outfile>${basedir}/target/program.exe</outfile>
                <errTitle></errTitle>
                <cmdLine></cmdLine>
                <chdir></chdir>
                <priority>normal</priority>
                <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                <supportUrl></supportUrl>
                <customProcName>true</customProcName>
                <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
                <manifest></manifest>
                <singleInstance>
                    <mutexName>MyLaunch4jMutex</mutexName>
                    <windowTitle></windowTitle>
                </singleInstance>
                <jre>
                    <path></path>
                    <minVersion>1.6.0</minVersion>
                    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
                    <initialHeapSize>64</initialHeapSize>
                    <maxHeapSize>512</maxHeapSize>
                </jre>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

### Output

When I run the .exe:

```
WebServer started at http://localhost:9200/program/
Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
    my.packages.resources
Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.6 03/25/2011 01:14 PM'
The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
service exception:
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1178)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$600(WebApplicationImpl.java:159)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$12.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:693)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$12.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:690)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:690)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:685)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:601)
```

On the other hand, when I run it from the Jar, it works fine and I get the following output:

```
WebServer started at http://localhost:9200/program/
Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
    my.packages.resources
Root resource classes found:
    class my.packages.resources.InfoRestResource
```

I would really appreciate any help in solving this issue! Thank you!

Comment: When you run with the webserver, are you classes available in the WEB-INF/classes folder?

Comment: No, I'm trying to run everything out of the .exe

Comment: So does everything get rolled up into a jar or are you executing this inside an IDE?  (I am just getting started with Jersey myself, after using RestEasy for a couple years.)

Comment: I'm executing the .jar and .exe from command line. (jar goes successful, exe fails)

Comment: I had exactly the same experience with Launch4J. It seems that EXE on the classpath gets happillly ignored by Jersey which means there is hardly anything Launch4J can do. Spring - on the other hands - auto-scans the EXE without any problem. I'm not sure whether this is a bug or a feature in Jersey.

Answer (score 0):

We had two modules first - `rest-api`, where all the classes jersey supposed to find were, and `restmod` that was the exe setup along with other classes (Main class with Jetty bootstrap, etc.).

Our Launch4j treatment was [unified in parent POM](https://virgo47.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/launch4j-and-embedded-web-container/) for all modules and it included JAR into EXE. After we merged `rest-api` with `restmod` (because it didn't make any sense for us anymore to keep them separated) we ran into this same problem. Devel/java worked just fine, but EXE version returned 404 for any endpoint. I debugged for a while and realized it seems to be Jersey's problem with EXE packaging. Found your questions and no answer.

What we did in the end: We introduced `restmod-exe` module. This time it did NOT contain any classes, it merely wrapped icons (two resources) into the JAR and included that into EXE as before (so no change to the prefered setup from our parent POM). There was also no change in how we managed dependencies (we put all of them to `dependency_libs` with `maven-dependency-plugin`). The only difference was that the main class was now in `restmod.jar` that was in that `depenency_libs` dir - but this causes no problem.

So we're back to two modules, but the second one's responsibility is EXE packaging and nothing else. Works for us.

BTW: The linked blogpost also deals with problem how to deploy WAR structure from EXE, which was our case before (using Jetty). Now it isn't - but it just demonstrates that Jersey is not the only one not willing to deal with EXE/ZIPs in classpath.